# Ajax Error Function Not Firing

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

My function executes perfectly when there are results to display. However, when there are no results or, in my case, program host records to display I would like for a message to display for "No Results". However, nothing happens. Any ideas? Thanks for the help!

```
$('#Lookup').click(function() {
var form_data = $('#validation-form').serializeArray();

$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url('opportunity/search_existing_program_host'); ?>",
    type: 'POST',
    data: form_data,
    cache: false,
    success: function(server_response) {
        var data = $.parseJSON(server_response);
        var html = '', program_host;

        html += '<tr><th>Program Host Name</th><th>Location</th><th>Session Prefix</th><th>Agency No.</th></tr>';
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            program_host = data[i];
            html += '<tr><td>' + program_host.Program_Host_Name + '</td><td>' + program_host.Address_1 + ', ' + program_host.City + ', ' + program_host.State + '</td><td>' + program_host.Session_Number_Prefix + '</td><td>' + program_host.Agency_Number + '</td></tr>';
        }

        $('#existing_program_hosts').append(html);
    },
    error: function() {
        //alert('Error');
        var html = '';

        html += '<tr><th>No Results</th></tr>';
        $('#existing_program_hosts').append(html);
    }
});

$('#Create_Host_btn').show();

})
```

Here is my function for returning the results:

```
function search_existing_program_host() {
    $Program_Host_Name = $this->input->post('Program_Host_Name');
    $Address_1 = $this->input->post('Address_1');

    $program_hosts = $this->ion_auth_model->search_existing_program_host($Program_Host_Name, $Address_1);

    foreach($program_hosts as $program_host):
        $results[] = array(
            "Program_Host_Name"         => "$program_host->Name",
            "Session_Number_Prefix"     => "$program_host->Session_Number_Prefix",
            "Agency_Number"             => "$program_host->Agency_Number",
            "Address_1"                 => "$program_host->Address_1",
            "Address_2"                 => "$program_host->Address_2",
            "Zip_Code"                  => "$program_host->Zip_Code",
            "Primary_Phone_Number"      => "$program_host->Primary_Phone_Number",
            "Secondary_Phone_Number"    => "$program_host->Secondary_Phone_Number",
            "Fax_Number"                => "$program_host->Fax_Number",
            "Number_501c3"              => "$program_host->Number_501c3",
            "Expiration_501c3"          => "$program_host->Expiration_501c3",
            "City"                      => "$program_host->City",
            "State"                     => "$program_host->State"
        );
    endforeach;

    echo json_encode($results);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd do something like:

```
$('#Lookup').click(function() {
var form_data = $('#validation-form').serializeArray();
var html = '<tr><th>No Results</th></tr>';

$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url('opportunity/search_existing_program_host'); ?>",
    type: 'POST',
    data: form_data,
    cache: false,
    success: function(server_response) {
        var data = $.parseJSON(server_response);
        var program_host;

        if (server_response != null){
            html += '<tr><th>Program Host Name</th><th>Location</th><th>Session Prefix</th><th>Agency No.</th></tr>';
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                program_host = data[i];
                html += '<tr><td>' + program_host.Program_Host_Name + '</td><td>' + program_host.Address_1 + ', ' + program_host.City + ', ' + program_host.State + '</td><td>' + program_host.Session_Number_Prefix + '</td><td>' + program_host.Agency_Number + '</td></tr>';
            }
         }

    },
    error: function(e, textStatus) {
        // perhaps you want something a little more custom here?
        html += '<tr><th>' + textStatus + '</th></tr>';
    },
    complete: function(){
       $('#existing_program_hosts').append(html);
    }
});
```

Comment: Depending on if `data` can be an empty array, perhaps a better check would be `if (data)` which would be a shortcut for `if (data != null && data.length)`

Comment: I still am left with no response back when no results are returned. The error function is not firing.

Answer (score 0):

In the "success" function, you might have to check the value of "server_response" to see if it's null.  Wrap the code inside the success function with a check

```
if (server_response != null) {
....current code...
} else {
...do soemthing if no data is returned.
}
```

Comment: Still not working for me. It seems to me that success does not execute if the result is empty. However, error does nothing either.

Answer (score 0):

Update your function like:

```
function search_existing_program_host() {
    $Program_Host_Name = $this->input->post('Program_Host_Name');
    $Address_1 = $this->input->post('Address_1');

    $program_hosts = $this->ion_auth_model->search_existing_program_host($Program_Host_Name, $Address_1);

    $results = array();
    foreach($program_hosts as $program_host):
        $results[] = array(
            "Program_Host_Name"         => "$program_host->Name",
            "Session_Number_Prefix"     => "$program_host->Session_Number_Prefix",
            "Agency_Number"             => "$program_host->Agency_Number",
            "Address_1"                 => "$program_host->Address_1",
            "Address_2"                 => "$program_host->Address_2",
            "Zip_Code"                  => "$program_host->Zip_Code",
            "Primary_Phone_Number"      => "$program_host->Primary_Phone_Number",
            "Secondary_Phone_Number"    => "$program_host->Secondary_Phone_Number",
            "Fax_Number"                => "$program_host->Fax_Number",
            "Number_501c3"              => "$program_host->Number_501c3",
            "Expiration_501c3"          => "$program_host->Expiration_501c3",
            "City"                      => "$program_host->City",
            "State"                     => "$program_host->State"
        );
    endforeach;

    $return = array('success' => (count($results)>0), 'results' => $results);

    echo json_encode($results);

}
```

And your AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url('opportunity/search_existing_program_host'); ?>",
    type: 'POST',
    data: form_data,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(server_response) {
        if (!server_response.success) {
           alert("No Results");
        } else {
           var data = server_response.results;
           var html = '', program_host;

           html += '<tr><th>Program Host Name</th><th>Location</th><th>Session Prefix</th><th>Agency No.</th></tr>';
           for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
               program_host = data[i];
               html += '<tr><td>' + program_host.Program_Host_Name + '</td><td>' + program_host.Address_1 + ', ' + program_host.City + ', ' + program_host.State + '</td><td>' + program_host.Session_Number_Prefix + '</td><td>' + program_host.Agency_Number + '</td></tr>';
           }

           $('#existing_program_hosts').append(html);
        }
    },
    error: function() {
        //alert('Error');
        var html = '';

        html += '<tr><th>No Results</th></tr>';
        $('#existing_program_hosts').append(html);
    }
});
```

Declare `$results = array();` before your foreach, and if haven't results, `(count($results)>0)` will return `FALSE` and `server_response.results` will be 0.
You don't need `parseJSON`, just declare `dataType: 'json'` in your ajax function.

Comment: This is still not firing for me. It seems to me that success does not execute if the result is empty. However, error does nothing either.

Comment: You can post your PHP code return? Generally I use a variable to return json, and add a index `success`.

Comment: I updated my original post with the return function from my controller. Thanks for the help.